Unable to serialize kotlin data class with retrofit
I'm learning kotlin and have been trying to get some data from the internet, but I keep running into the same error. For this example I tried to generate an image with the OpenAI API.
Here's my retrofit and request builder:

private const val BASE_URL =
    "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/"

class AuthorizationInterceptor(private val token: String) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization:", "Bearer $token")
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(AuthorizationInterceptor("myToken")).build())
    .build()

object GensApi {
    val retrofitService : GensApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(GensApiService::class.java)
    }
}

interface GensApiService {
    @POST("generations")
    suspend fun getGen(
    @Body
    request: Request
    ): String
}

@Serializable
data class Request (
    val prompt: String,
    val size: String
)

This is the actual call from my viewmodel:
    GensApi.retrofitService.getGen(request = Request("Icon of an apple", "256x256"))

Unfortunately, whenever I build the app I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class               com.example.apiconnecttest       
for method GensApiService.getGen
    at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
    at retrofit2.Utils.parameterError(Utils.java:60)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:781)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:325)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:206)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy1.getGen(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.apiconnecttest.screens.FruitViewmodel$fetchFruits$1$fruitsList$1.invokeSuspend(FruitViewmodel.kt:24)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:100)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
   Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Request' is not found.   Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.PlatformKt.serializerNotRegistered(Platform.kt:31)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersJvmKt.serializer(SerializersJvm.kt:77)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.Serializer.serializer(Serializer.kt:21)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.Factory.requestBodyConverter(Factory.kt:37)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextRequestBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:315)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.requestBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:293)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:778)```

I've tried to figure out what I'm doing wrong but can't seem to find it :(
I've tried to ensure the serializer plugin is applied properly in my build.gradle.kts. It currently looks like this
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10"
}

dependencies {
...
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0")
}

